# How to press down-arrow key in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to do press down-arrow key in the address search box after entering the address in Robot Framework

I'm using the [Press Key](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Key) keyword, but it's not working (it enters the key value in the text box) and I tried other methods, but the library is not added to red.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation         Test the Web site
Library               Selenium2Library
Library               pyautogui
Library               OperatingSystem
Library               ImageHorizonLibrary
 *** Keywords ***
 search the address
    Open Browser    http://localhost.com:4000     chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    Input Text    //*[@id=\"homepage\"]/section[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/app-address-search-bar/div/input    newyork
    press key    //*[@id=\"homepage\"]/section[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/app-address-search-bar/div/input   //25
```

I excepted that after I type the address in the text box, and I want to press the down-arrow key to select the address (from the drop-down-list).

Comment: What is the error that you're facing?

Answer (score 3):

You used an incorrect code for the key - it has to be prefixed with a backslash, not a slash:

```
press key    //*[@id=\"homepage\"]/section[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/app-address-search-bar/div/input   \\25
```

And a personal recommendation - you'd been even better to use the `"\u"` codes. This one's is `\ue015`.

The full list of the codes can be [found in Selenium's source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.py).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
press keys  your_locator  ARROW_DOWN
```

As 'press key' is deprecated in the latest version of seleniumLibrary.